# Mocking new object creation with PhpSpec in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpspec

I have a class called `Campaign` that is responsible for booking single campaign in the external API. I have `EntryBooking` class that is responsible for preparing the entry and booking it using the `Campaign` class. There might be instances where I want to create more than one campaign so for each campaign I want to create a new `Campaign` object and call `book()` method on it. (Each campaign has its own `Campaign` object)

The issue I'm having is that I want to unit test the `EntryBooking` class and I want to mock `Campaign` objects.

I am using the `BenConstable/phpspec-laravel` package so I have access to facades in my specs.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
# EntryBookingSpec.php
function it_should_book_campaigns_for_entry(Entry $entry, Campaign $campaignMock)
{
    $campaignMock->book()->shouldBeCalled();
    App::instance(Campaign::class, $campaignMock);

    $this->bookForEntry($entry);
}
```

-

```
# EntryBooking.php
class EntryBooking
{
    public function bookForEntry(Entry $entry): void
    {
        $campaign = App::make(Campaign::class);
        // do the processing and set values for $campaign
        $campaign->book();
    }
}
```

I am trying with `App::instance()` because in live environment, the `App::make()` will create a new instance each time it's called, but while testing I want it to return the very same object so I can make my assertions on it.

**The problem** is that the predictions fail. Even though I call `$campaignMock->book()->shouldBeCalled();` and in tested class I call `$campaign->book()` I still get:

```
some predictions failed:
    Double\vendor\package\Campaign\P1:
      No calls have been made that match:
        Double\vendor\package\Campaign\P1->book()
      but expected at least one.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you use Dependency Injection using constructors PhpSpec will automatically create a mocked object from your `MethodProphecy`, but if you want your service container to return mocked object you need to pass it a wrapped object on your own.
So changing the following

```
App::instance(Campaign::class, $campaignMock);
```

to

```
App::instance(Campaign::class, $campaignMock->getWrappedObject());
```

Makes everything work as expected.

**EDIT**

Or even better, mock the Service Container completely:

```
App::shouldReceive('make')
    ->with(Campaign::class)
    ->andReturn($campaignMock->getWrappedObject());
```

And call `\Mockery::close()` in your `letGo()` function.
There is no way for the class to receive concrete class implementations and you actually test if the class made resolve requests to the Service Container in the first place.

Comment: Or even better, create a factory and use it as a dependency and mock the factory ;)